# Does sender application for chrome casting of DRM driven videos through api has different implementation than ones from other resource?

Tags: android, chromecast, drm

**I'm getting videos in my application from an api through DRM encoded paths.**

1. I've to ask either the **sender application** be written same as they've
   been written for **sample applications** I've been implementing lastly? They had videos from both, local and dynamic resources.
2. Does the changes required to be applied in **receiver application**
       written in the **api**?

*Hoping for a sincere response, Thank You.*

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: I'm in search of code for passing Widevine DRM path from sender but can't find one. If can you please provide me some information about this topic, any sample or something like that, it would be great.